# На каких процессорах и материнках лучше собрать компьютерный кластер на ~1000 потоков?

Tags: многопоточность, железо

Допустим, хочу собрать компьютерный кластер производительностью, например, в 1000 потоков со скоростью примерно как современные i5 процессоры. Но, в принципе, можно и медленнее, но тогда потоков сделать побольше. В общем, на каких процессорах и материнках будет достигнута такая производительность за наименьшую стоимость?

В интернете часто упоминают, что для этого используют процессоры AMD, но их там много, и я затрудняюсь выбрать.

Comment: Каков характер вашей задачи, что она требует столько потоков? Может, для неё лучше просто взять одну видеокарту?

Comment: Комбинаторные переборы. SIMD операции не подходят.

Comment: Возможно, есть смысл сперва попробовать аренду серваков у облачных провайдеров. Можно за небольшие деньги потестировать Intel и AMD, ARM и Epyc.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Идея правильная, поддерживаю. НО! Ряд облачников не сообщают ТТХ машин, где будет счёт. Иные - обещают конкретику, например, ThreadRipper, а затем внезапно перекидывают "куда-нибудь", имитируя схожие расчётные возможности. Мы пробовали так: звонили хостерам, кто собирает новые сервера, договаривались о "первой ночи" (то есть мы закачиваем пласт данных, что-то считаем в течение 24 - 72 часов, смотрим, прощаемся, они потом тупо перенакатывают ОС).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно пять лет назад, проанализировав все варианты, мы пришли к выводу, что оптимальный вариант для биоинформатических расчётов без использования GPU (для этого у нас есть отдельные мини-кластеры) - топовые или предтоповые Ryzen. Как итог, последний собранный кластер содержит 15 машин на базе Ryzen 3950. Итого, имеем честных 16x15 = 240 ядер и 32x15 = 480 потоков. Не 1000, но, насколько я знаю, на 31 единице тоже можно собрать.

Почему именно такой вариант? Предыдущее поколение процессоров нам обошлось недорого, были использованы недорогие, но надёжные (по статистике) материнские платы. Ну, и плюсом послужило то, что мы умеем оптимизировать под Ryzen'ы :)